# ¿Como generar un JSON de una consulta en MySQL y verla atraves de una URL?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Buen día compañeros quisiera saber como realizar este proceso, obtener los datos de una consulta de MySQL en un JSON pero lo pueda obtener mediante una URL o en caso de pruebas `postman`, los lenguajes que suelo manejar son `Laravel` y estuve intentando con `nodejs`

La consulta que quiero hacer es

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios;
```

En node tengo esto

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'SuperSecreto',
        database : 'biometricopruebas',
        port: '3307'
    });
    // res.locals.connect();
    // next();
});
```

y esto obtendria supuestamente

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from usuarios', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
    });
});
```

Pongo esto porque hasta el momento es lo que he intentado, no se si exista otra mejor manera de hacerlo, ya que este pequeño API sera para angular y una app en android, espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: El código que has puesto parece estar bien, lo único que no entiendo donde esta el problema. No consigues hacer la petición para obtener los datos? O no sabes como levantar el servidor HTTP? . Personalmente no entendí la pregunta.

Comment: No consigo  hacer la petición, y no se si esto pueda servir para un servidor web

Comment: Mira esta demo que te hice, haber si te sirve. https://repl.it/@eugeni9872_72/SweetDizzySales

Comment: Agregale nodejs a los tags de la pregunta

Comment: Lo he logrado muy similar a lo de @EugeniBejan